# backport "declare -n" from BASH 4.4 to 4.2

Tags: bash

With Bash 4.4, I wrote scripts using "declare -n" but today I learned that when I give those to RedHat 7 users, the scripts fail because their BASH is 4.2.

Here's a small example of the problem, I wonder if you can advise me on good method to backport this to BASH 4.2:

```
#!/bin/bash

pwd=`pwd`
declare -A parms
parms[engine]=\"Sweave\"
parms[verbose]=FALSE
parms[tangle]=TRUE

## builds $parmstring by concatenating key=value pairs
catarr() {
        declare -n __p="$1"
        for k in "${!__p[@]}"
        do parmstring+=", $k=${__p[$k]}"
        done
}
parmstring=""
catarr parms

echo ${parmstring[*]}
```

The output is supposed to be like this:

```
$ bash bashmre.sh
, engine="Sweave", verbose=FALSE, tangle=TRUE
```

But on old BASH, RedHat says declare does not allow "-n".

Comment: If you could have the effect of the feature without built-in support, what would be the point of adding the built-in support?

Comment: BTW, `paramstring+="foo"` is just appending to `paramstring[0]`, so there's no point to the `[*]`.

Comment: That said, do you ever actually *use* `catarr` with a target other than `parms`? If you don't, hardcode the array name and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for can be achieved using `eval`:

```
#!/bin/bash

pwd=`pwd`
declare -A parms
parms[engine]=\"Sweave\"
parms[verbose]=FALSE
parms[tangle]=TRUE

## builds $parmstring by concatenating key=value pairs
catarr() {
    eval keys=(\"\${!$1[@]}\")
    for k in "${keys[@]}"
    do
        eval val=\${$1[$k]}
        parmstring+=", $k=$val"
    done
}
parmstring=""
catarr parms

echo ${parmstring[*]}
```

I tested this on bash 4.2.37 and got the desired output

Comment: Needs quotes in the `eval`'d strings -- right now you're running `keys=(${!parms[@]})`, which isn't correct; it needs to be `keys=("${!parms[@]}")` to handle all possible keys correctly. Test with `parms["extended key"]="two words"`

Comment: Much better. I'd suggest making it just `echo "$parmstring"` -- since the string is just a string and not an array, there's no point to treating it as the latter -- but that's just quibbling.

Comment: I agree. I was just trying to change as little as possible from the example script

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all clean, but you can generate and then execute code. To try to keep the generation safe, use `printf %q` for substituted values.

```
catarr() {
  local eval_str

  printf -v eval_str '
    for k in "${!%q[@]}"; do
      parmstring+=", $k=${%q[$k]}"
    done
  ' "$1" "$1"
  eval "$eval_str"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand it, but it works, so it is +1 for me.  I wish others here would vote, help choose correct answer. Would you look at @shay's suggestion? It looks OK to me. Do you have an opinion?

Comment: There's a bug in shay's answer which I've noted in a comment there, but that's easily fixed (by adding extra quotes). The bigger problem with that approach (substituting `$1` into a string to `eval` without escaping) is code injection through a hostile variable name -- if someone ran `catarr '}foo[@]}); run-an-arbitrary-command; #'`, this version would just throw an error, and that one would run the chosen arbitrary command. That's not a risk if your attacker can run arbitrary commands *anyhow*, but it is one if you're generating variable names off of data you're reading (filenames, etc).

Comment: See https://ideone.com/WIHBAv for an example of a successful code injection attack against the other code even as-edited with the extra quotes; compare to https://ideone.com/I4QWPl, trying that same attack against this answer, which emits a syntax error but doesn't actually run the payload.

Answer (score 0):

I gave +1 to the answers by @Charles Duffy and @shay, but in the end I did not use either answer.

I took the path that Charles suggested in a comment to my original post. I re-wrote the thing so there is one separate function for each of the arrays that needs to be concatenated. In the actual application were we are using this, there are two arrays, "parms" and "myopts" and so I end up with functions named catparms and catmyopts

```
catparms(){
    for k in "${!parms[@]}"
    do parmstring+=", $k=${parms[$k]}"
    done
}

catmyopts(){
    for k in "${!myopts[@]}"
    do optstring+=", $k=${myopts[$k]}"
    done
}
```

If I had a lot of arrays floating around, that method would become tedious.

If that happens, I am pretty sure I would go back to the method I used relying on Bash 4.4 and tell the people with old Bash they have to upgrade or forget about it. I would need to learn how to add code in the script that would detect the current Bash version and terminate if it is not 4.3 or higher.  I've not done it, but could.